# Java running in Oracle - the imported jars

Tags: java, oracle11g

I am trying to get a small java class to load into Oracle 11g so I can run it and call it from PL/SQL. I coded and compiled the class on my local machine in eclipse and it compiles fine.  I packaged it up into a jar (with the other jar files it depends on in the jar).  They I tried loading my jar into Oracle 11g.  Everything loads in, unfortunately when it loads my custom java class, it stays invalid and when I try to compile it within Oracle it says it can't find references to the classes (the ones I had packaged in my jar with my class).

Is there some other sort of setting I need to configure?

Here is what my custom classes code looks like:

```
import com.flashline.registry.openapi.base.OpenAPIException;
import com.flashline.registry.openapi.entity.*;
import com.flashline.registry.openapi.service.v300.FlashlineRegistry;
import com.flashline.registry.openapi.service.v300.FlashlineRegistryServiceLocator;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class AssetExtractor {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


   static Logger LOG;
   static AuthToken authToken = null;

   static FlashlineRegistry repository = null;
   static URL repoURL;


    public static FlashlineRegistry getRepository()
    {
        if(repository == null)
            try
            {
                try{
                    repoURL = new URL("https://myserver/oer/services/FlashlineRegistry");
                }catch(MalformedURLException mue)
                {
                    LOG.error(mue);
                }

                repository = (new FlashlineRegistryServiceLocator()).getFlashlineRegistry(repoURL);
                LOG.debug((new StringBuilder()).append("Created repository at URL=").append(repoURL.toString()).toString());
            }
            catch(ServiceException e)
            {
                LOG.error(e, e);
            }
        return repository;
    }

    public static AuthToken getAuthToken()
    {
        if(authToken == null)
            try
            {
                authToken = getRepository().authTokenCreate("user", "password");
                LOG.debug("Created auth token.");
            }
            catch(OpenAPIException e)
            {
                LOG.error(e, e);
            }
            catch(RemoteException e)
            {
                LOG.error(e, e);
            }
        else
            try
            {
                getRepository().authTokenValidate(authToken);
            }
            catch(OpenAPIException e)
            {
                LOG.info("Auth token was invalid.  Recreating auth token");
                authToken = null;
                return getAuthToken();
            }
            catch(RemoteException re)
            {
                LOG.error("Remote exception occured during creation of suth token after determined to be invalid", re);
                re.printStackTrace();
                authToken = null;
            }
        return authToken;
    }

    public static String getAssetXML(String strAssetID)
    {
        String strAsset = null;
        try
        {
            strAsset = getRepository().assetReadXml(getAuthToken(), Long.parseLong(strAssetID));
        }
        catch(OpenAPIException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(RemoteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strAsset;
    }

}
```

And all the *.jar files for the imports are inside my AssetExtractor.jar

The command I've been using to load the jar into oracle is:

```
loadjava -v -f -resolve -resolver "((* OER) (* PUBLIC))" -user oer/***** AssetExtractor.jar
```

Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: And I already tried setting the classpath in my OS where my DB is, I also saw in one manual setting the classpath in the extproc.ora file and so I've also tried that.  So far none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that if I do the following it solves nearly all my problems:

Edit the Oracle users' .profile to SET and EXPORT the CLASSPATH, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_HOME, JAVA_HOME with the correct paths

SQLPlus as sys as sysdba

```
EXEC dbms_java.grant_permission( 'OER', 'SYS:java.util.PropertyPermission', 'java.class.path', 'write' );
```

OS Commandline as oracle user:

```
loadjava –v –grant PUBLIC <jar> -user oer/****** for all jars
```

SQLPlus as OER user

```
DECLARE
   v_classpath VARCHAR2(4000);
   v_path VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   v_classpath := DBMS_JAVA.set_property('java.class.path',    '/opt/oracle/102/jdk/lib:/mnt/hgfs/vmshare/rex_lib/aler-axis-   1.2.1.jar:/mnt/hgfs/vmshare/rex_lib/aler-axis-jaxrpc-1.2.1.jar:/mnt/hgfs/vmshare/rex_lib/client.rex-   11.1.1.5.0.jar:/mnt/hgfs/vmshare/rex_lib/commons-httpclient-3.0rc2-   flashline.jar:/mnt/hgfs/vmshare/rex_lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar');
   v_path := DBMS_JAVA.set_property('java.path', '/opt/oracle/102/jdk/bin');
END;
/

alter java source "AssetExtractor" compile;
show errors
```

The only outstanding issue is that for some reason it still can't locate/resolve some of the Oracle OER classes (which should all be in the client.rex*.jar, I opened and saw them there.  If I can solve this part then I'm good to go.