# How to implement Java deserialize() in PL/SQL

Tags: java, serialization, plsql

I need to deserialize() a Java object stored in a BLOB. Database instance has no server-side Java loaded, and never gets one. I can't connect to the database with a Java code, only with SQL client such as TOAD. So the only option seems to be, implement deserialization in PL/SQL. Any ideas, how?

Comment: You don't have a JDBC driver to connect to the database from your application? If not how would you provide the data to deserialize to any PL/SQL and how would you trigger? - What you might try in this case: deserialize to a file and load that file into a blob manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deserialize java object from a blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768439/deserialize-java-object-from-a-blob)

Comment: @Thomas, no I can't connect from any external / unapproved app including Java including JDBC Driver, it's about security and it's strict.

Serialized Java Object is stored in a BLOB by another (approved) app.

Comment: @Kraal, it's no duplicate because I can't use Java, neither server- nor client-side.

Comment: If you can't use Java anywhere, why would you have a serialized Java object in the database?

Comment: @Kayaman, serialized Java Object is stored in a BLOB by another (approved) app.

Comment: The ideas that come to my mind are: 1. Don't even bother attempting to access it through TOAD and PL/SQL 2. Tell someone who's in charge that it would be stupid to attempt to process the data outside of a Java program, since serialization is a Java dependent mechanism 3. Complain to everyone that this is a ridiculous task and could very well mean that the design is flawed.

Comment: I still don't get it: does that approved app deserialize that blob or is it just seeing a blob? If it deserializes then why can't it write as well? If it reads only then how does the data get into the db? I guess manually, if so then you could do it as I suggested: serialize to a file and store that file in the database - after all a file is just a blob as well.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind this whole operation. What does the serialized object contain and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Why are you asking for the logic ? I can imagine different reasons that may lead to such a difficult-to-understand situation (3d party tool he can't modify, legacy data written with a tool he can't use anymore, desktop admins that refuse to install a JDK... <you name it>) Try rather to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but if there is no way to ask your "approved java app" to write the data you need in a readable form (is the data stored by a 3d party application you bought ? If so, can't they provide you with a tool to achieve what you want ?) , and if you can't write your own java program to read these serialized object, I guess that the only way to do what you're trying to achieve is:

1. Read the Java Object Serialization specification located at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html (for JDK 8)
2. Make sure you know the class you want to analyse (if objects are an instance of different classes this may help you filter the objects you're looking for)
3. Deserialize in PL/SQL the objects by following the serialization stream format and read the fields you're looking for.

This article can help you understand the serialization algorithm : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html

Note: I do not recommend this approach, you should rather find a way to store the data in a readable format.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. App and its data is legacy, I have no control over it. Do you know of any existing implementation of Java Object Serialization specification in PL/SQL?